# Road shape for elliptical wheels

Tags: geometry, functions

I noticed the problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401428/road-shape-for-square-wheels) and tried to extrapolate it to the case where the wheel becomes elliptical:

For an ellipse with semi-major and semi-minor axes of length $a$ and $b$, find a road curve which makes one point inside the ellipse *stable* (that is, making it have a constant altitude).

I'm currently stuck with finding the stable point. I guess it should be either one of the foci, but I'm stuck with the proof. But I discovered one fact that may help: if a point is stable, then the line between the stable point and the touching point of the wheel and the road **at any moment** should be perpendicular to the horizontal line. And I also have an intuition that if the stable point is the focus, then it has something to do with the optical characteristics of the ellipse.

Thanks for anyone who can help solve this problem!

Comment: The road shape is the curve of elliptic function $y=k dn(x,m)$ (where $k,m$ are parameter taking into account the specificities of the rolling ellipse). See this  question asked a year ago and the answer of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4326210/305862).

Comment: If you need more information, let me know.